# grid kendo-ui and json, data not show

Tags: kendo-ui, grid

I am trying to show in the data grid kendo ui, but there's something wrong in my code. Can anyone help.

The data are not shown in the grid

this is may json:

```
{
"dados": [
    {
        "t0010_id_bairro": 115,
        "t0020_id_empresa": 1,
        "t0001_id_cidade": 1,
        "t0010_descricao": "ATUBA",
        "t0010_situacao": 1
    }
]
```

}

this is my scrypt:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "http://localhost:23714/Bairro/getBydesc",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: "dados"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                t0010_id_bairro: { type: "number" },
                                t0020_id_empresa: { type: "number" },
                                t0001_id_cidade: { type: "number" },
                                t0010_descricao: { type: "string" },
                                t0010_situacao: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                height: 550,
                filterable: true,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "t0010_id_bairro",
                    filterable: false
                },
                    "t0020_id_empresa",
                    {
                        field: "t0001_id_cidade",
                        title: "Cidade"
                    }, {
                        field: "t0010_descricao",
                        title: "Nome"
                    }, {
                        field: "t0010_situacao",
                        title: "Sit"
                    }]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this is a result:
[not appear the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTuzv.png)

not appear the data

Answer (score 1):

You need put `data: "dados"` to `schema`:

```
schema: {
    ...
    data: "dados",
    ...
}
```

**Added fiddle:** http://dojo.telerik.com/Ijide

Comment: @alessandremartins then your transport read url not working properly, or return invalid json

Comment: my url returns a correct json, I tested the postman. but the data are not shown in datagrid

Comment: @alessandremartins did you check fiddle? i put raw data instead of transport